# Where can I find all command functions of Atom editor?

Tags: atom-editor

I can't find anywhere on the internet. I made some custom key bindings using stuff like:

```
    editor = @getModel()
bufferRow = editor.bufferPositionForScreenPosition(editor.getCursorScreenPosition()).row
if editor.isFoldedAtBufferRow(bufferRow)
  editor.unfoldBufferRow(bufferRow)
else
  editor.foldBufferRow(bufferRow)
```

and

```
atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()?.selectAll()
atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()?.pasteText()
atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()?.save()
```

But I had to search so much. No list of all functions to use?

PS: Best thing close to it for me was: https://gist.github.com/philipmadeley/1fb35efdf5ab639c12c6

Comment: http://flight-manual.atom.io/ also https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.16.0/AtomEnvironment

Answer (score 1):

Atom has an abundance of documentation over at https://atom.io/docs/

More specifically, this would be what you were looking for:
https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.16.0/TextEditor